# React Quill text editor rendering data with double quote

Tags: html, reactjs, text-editor, quill, react-quill

I am using React Quill text editor to save data into database. The issue i am facing is when i am retrieving the saved data it is rendering with " "  (double quote).

**eg: data is saved like this:**

```
<p>Pick up from other emirates is available at an extra charge.</p>
```

**But it is rendering like this with double quote:**

```
"<p>Pick up from other emirates is available at an extra charge.</p>"
```

**Here is the screenshot:**
[image]

**using ReactQuill text editor like this:**

```
<ReactQuill 
    theme="snow" 
    style={{ height: "100px" }} 
    id="pickup"
    value={pickup} onChange={setPickup} />
```

**Rendering data like this:**

```
<div className='col-12'> {values.pickup} </div>
```

Thanks